# How to show a post only to the user who posted and the admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to limit who can see posts in one specific category, so that only to the user who posted it and the admin can see them?

I have set up a custom post type with its own template, a custom post status and a new category for this. I want posts in this category only to be visible to the user who posted it and the admin.

I tried to do this on the code below, but it doesn't work - only the admin can see the posts.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.

 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php 
          $user_id = the_author_meta('ID');
          $admin_ch = get_user_by('id', 1);
          $cu_user = get_current_user_id();

      if($cu_user == $user_id || $cu_user == $admin_ch) {
         while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <div class="container-block">
          <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <div id="sh">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() && $meta = screenr_posted_on( false ) ) : ?>
                <?php
                endif; ?>

                <?php
                  if ( ! get_theme_mod( 'disable_featured_image', 0 ) ) {
                      if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                          echo '<div class="entry-thumb">';
                          the_post_thumbnail('screenr-blog-list');
                          echo '</div>';
                      }
                  }
                ?>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
          </div>

                <div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="p-date">
                  On
                    <?php $post_date = get_the_date( 'l F j, Y' ); echo $post_date; ?>
                  By
                <?php $user_name = the_author_meta( 'display_name', $ID ); echo $user_name; ?>
              </span>
                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php
                    the_content( sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
                        wp_kses( esc_html__( 'Continue reading %s', 'screenr' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ),
                        the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
                    ) );

                    wp_link_pages( array(
                        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'screenr' ),
                        'after'  => '</div>',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
           <?php show_publish_button();  ?>
          </article><!-- #post-## -->
        </div>

                <?php endwhile; // End of the loop.
} else {
  echo "You can't show this";
}


         ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: but sadly it visible the post only for admin

Comment: What have yo tried to debug your code? Did you try printing out the values for `$cu_user`, `$user_id` and `$admin_ch` to see if they were correct? Also, please see [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - most of the code you posted is unrelated to the problem (e.g.  how you are displaying the post is not relevant) so update your code to include just the relevant parts, so it will be easier for us to see whats happening in the code that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me leave this as a comment but on this line:

```
  if($cu_user == $user_id || $admin_ch) {
```

Change it to:

```
  if($cu_user == $user_id || $cu_user == $admin_ch) {
```

As it is written, after the or, there isn't an argument. You need to give an argument there too.

Also the proper function is:

```
get_the_author_meta('ID')
```

Comment: This may seem simple but are you sure you haven't changed the ID for admin? That is a good practice for security reasons. Maybe double check that before we proceed.

Comment: Yes I am sure , I haven't changed the ID for admin

Comment: Also, remove the $ in front of ID here: '$user_id = the_author_meta( $ID );' So it should read $user_id = the_author_meta('ID');

Comment: after removed the $ it show this post only for admin not for posted user

Comment: No, I am trying now

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code you have please?

Comment: And how is this behaving now? Who is it showing posts for?

Comment: but sadly it visible the post only for admin

Comment: Echo out $user_id and see what the value is.